# linux - export output from apachetop to file

Tags: linux, shell

Is it possible to export output from apachetop to file? Something like this: "apachetop > file", but because apachetop is running "forever", so this command is also running forever. I just need to obtain actual output from this program and handle it in my GTK# application.
Every answer will be very appreciated.
Matej.

Comment: You may find the manual page for *tail* of interest, either as a command to directly leverage or an idea to duplicate in your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

{ apachetop > file 2>&1 & sleep 1; kill $! ; }

but no guarantees :)

Another way using linux is to find out the /dev/vcsN device that is being used when running the program and reading from that file directly.  It contains a copy of the screen data for a given VT; I'm not sure if there is a applicable device for a pty.

Comment: Output of your command looks good but it is full of escape sequence characters (when I use vim, cat -v or I give it to my gtk# application): ^[[?1049h^[[1;24r^[(B^[[m^[[4l^[[?7h^[[?1h^[=^[[H^[[2Jlast hit: 00:00:00^[[1;28Hatop runtime:  0 days, 00:00:00^[[1;72H18:00:55^M^[[2d^[(B^[[0;1mAll:            0 reqs (   0.0/sec)          0.0B (    0.0B/sec)       0.0B/req^M^[[3d^[(B^[[m2xx:.... I also tried cat file -v > file,
sed 's/^[[^a-zA-Z]\+[a-zA-Z]//g' file or sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g" file > file2. output from strings was the best, but not perfect. Can u help me?

Comment: Try sed -r "s/\x1B\[([0-9]{1,2}(;[0-9]{1,2})?)?[m|K]//g". Source: serverfault.com/questions/71285/.

Comment: Thanks for fast answer, but output from vim is: ^[[?1049h^[[1;24r^[(B^[[4l^[[?7h^[[?1h^[=^[[H^[[2Jlast hit: 00:00:00^[[1;28Hatop runtime:  0 days, 00:00:00^[[1;72H18:00:55^M^[[2d^[(BAll:            0 reqs (   0.0/sec)          0.0B (    0.0B/sec)       0.0B/req^M^[[3d^[(B2xx:       0 ( 0.0%) 3xx:       0 ( 0.0%) 4xx:     0 ( 0.0%) 5xx:     0 ( 0.0%)^M^[[4d^[(BR (  1s):       0 reqs (   0.0/sec)          0.0B (    0.0B/sec)       0.0B/req^M^[[5d^[(B2xx:           0 ( 0.0%) 3xx:       0 ( 0.0%) 4xx:     0 ( 0.0%) 5xx:     0 ( 0.0%)^M^[[7d

Comment: There was also an answer I got the last one from on using the col -b command. Maybe try that. Looking at that sed command it doesn't seem complete. If col fails I suggest googling stripping out escape sequences from a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Well indirectly apachetop is using the access.log file to get it's data.

Look at

> /var/log/apache2/access.log

You'll simply have to parse the file to get the info you're looking for!/var/log/apache2/access.log